# Calculating center of rectangle with coordinate, length, width and angle

Tags: java, geolocation, geometry

I want to determine the center of a rotated rectangle. This rectangle has to be calculated first (see figure). For this the distance in all four directions from the existing coordinate p(x1, y1) is known (bow, port, star, stern). The orientation of the square is also given in degrees.

[image]

The easiest solution for me was to calculate a rectangle around the blue axes and then determine the center of this rectangle. Unfortunately I already have a problem with determining the vertices of the square considering the rotation.

Does anyone know how to calculate the coordinates of the vertices with these inputs (preferred in Java)? If someone knows another simpler approach, I would be very grateful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question is mostly math related and not really a programming one. It should be asked on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `star` axis has rotation `phi` relative to OX axis, then direction vector for it is

```
sx, sy = cos(phi), sin(phi)   //don't forget about radians and degrees
```

perpendicular (`bow` direction) vector is

```
bx, by = -sy, sx
```

So the topmost vertex at the picture has coordinates

```
tx = px + star * sx + bow * bx
ty = py + star * sy + bow * by
```

Bottom vertex:

```
ux = px - port * sx - stern * bx
uy = py - port * sy - stern * by
```

Rectangle center is middle of these vertices

```
cx = px + sx * (star - port) / 2 + bx * (bow - stern) / 2
cy = py + sy * (star - port) / 2 + by * (bow - stern) / 2
```

And reverting `b*` variables to `sx, sy`:
and accounting for desired angle direction:

```
cx = px + sx * (star - port) / 2 + sy * (bow - stern) / 2
cy = py - sy * (star - port) / 2 + sx * (bow - stern) / 2
```

Comment: I checked your answer on a simple example with the following input data: pos_x = 0, pos_y = 0, bow = 10, stern = 20, port = 5, star = 5. I checked it for 4 different heading values: 0°, 90°, 180°, 270°. I expect for this input to get the following four position: (0,-5), (-5,0),(0,5) and (5,0). For 0 and 180° I get the right solution. For 90° and 270°, however, your solution exchanges the results. Do you have a idea how to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you have missed that bx, by values differ from sx, sy. I added final expression with sx/sy only. For 90: `cx = 0 + 0 - 1 * (-5) = 5`

Comment: Yes exactly, for 90° I get the value 5 like you, but the value -5 should come out. At the moment the point P is located rather at the front of the polygon. So if the polygon looks to the right, the point has be moved to the left. This would result in -5 for 90°. Vice versa for 270° (move to the right, result = 5). Do you understand my problem with your solution?

Comment: Seems you are using another angle direction. For example, your picture shows angle about 45 degrees and center.x definitely lies at the right of P - positive value. But it is not a problem - I just changed signs in final formula.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative formula (source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238090180_A_Study_on_the_efficiency_enhancement_of_automatic_radar_tracking_and_analyses_of_marine_traffic_in_Tokyo_Bay):

```
c_cog = Math.toRadians(course);
double xc = pos_x + (bow - stern) * Math.sin(course) / 2 + (star-port) * Math.sin(course+90) / 2;
double yc = pos_y + (bow - stern) * Math.cos(course)/2 + (star-port) * Math.cos(course+90) / 2;
```

Comment: 1) This is the same formula as mine with changed angle direction (because cos(a+90)=-sin(a) and sin(a+90)=cos(a)) 2) You mix degrees and radians in erroneous way